# How to fetch a association on the other side of a ManyToMany?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have the following model: a "classical" many-to-many book/author association but with 2 peculiarities.

1. Author does not have an association to Books.
2. The Author personal data is stored on other associated entity, called Person.

The model:

```
public class Book {
   @ManyToMany
   List<Author> authors;
}

public class Author {
    @OneToOne
    Person person;
}

public class Person {
    String name;
}
```

I would like to write a service which, given a book, will return all the authors associated with it. I would also like to retrieve the personal data avoiding the N+1 problem.

Inside my Book repo I wrote a custom query like that:

```
@Query("select b.authors from Book b join b.authors a join fetch a.person where b = :book")
List<Author> listAuthors(@Param("book") Book book);
```

But I have the folloiwing error:

> query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched
> association was not present in the select list (...)

I could manage to solve it by adding the association to Books on the Author side and fetching Person from it. Unfortunately , in my case, it is really desirable that Authors do not know about Books.

Is there any way to fetch Person data from a Book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using an EXISTS clause:

```
@Query("select a from Author a join fetch a.person " + 
       "where exists (select 1 from Book b where b = :book and a member of b.authors)")
List<Author> listAuthors(@Param("book") Book book);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a Hibernate Bug [HHH-14116](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14116) - I recently stumbled across a related bug and in the discussion in the Hibernate Chat this bug was filed too. There is already [a fix](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/3482), but AFAIK it has not been released yet.

One way to circumvent this would be to have the relationship be bi-directional and query from the Author side.
Otherwise you could do it with a subquery, but I'm not sure whether that works with Spring Data JPA:

```
select a from Author a join fetch a.person where a.id in
    (select a.id from Book b join b.authors a where b = :book)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting Person with your @Query as well?

```
@Query("select b.authors, a.person from Book b join b.authors a join fetch a.person where b = :book")
List<Author> listAuthors(@Param("book") Book book);
```